# "Could not unlink /var/run/tor/control: Permission denied" on tor start from vidalia

Tags: tor

I updated tor to latest PPA version yesterday and it gives this when starting Tor:

```
Jan 20 14:00:08.147 [Notice] Tor v0.2.2.16-alpha (git-61e0079ab25db6c3). This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Linux i686)
Jan 20 14:00:08.147 [Warning] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
Jan 20 14:00:08.147 [Notice] Initialized libevent version 1.4.13-stable using method epoll. Good.
Jan 20 14:00:08.147 [Notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jan 20 14:00:08.147 [Notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jan 20 14:00:08.148 [Notice] Opening Control listener on /var/run/tor/control
Jan 20 14:00:08.148 [Warning] Could not unlink /var/run/tor/control: Permission denied
Jan 20 14:00:08.148 [Notice] Closing partially-constructed listener Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jan 20 14:00:08.148 [Notice] Closing partially-constructed listener Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jan 20 14:00:08.148 [Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Jan 20 14:00:08.148 [Error] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

It Seems the problem is the line that says:

```
Jan 20 14:00:08.148 [Warning] Could not unlink /var/run/tor/control: Permission
```

Running Vidalia as root gives these:

```
Jan 20 20:56:08.495 [Notice] Tor v0.2.2.16-alpha (git-61e0079ab25db6c3). This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Linux i686)
Jan 20 20:56:08.506 [Warning] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
Jan 20 20:56:08.507 [Notice] Initialized libevent version 1.4.13-stable using method epoll. Good.
Jan 20 20:56:08.507 [Notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jan 20 20:56:08.507 [Notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jan 20 20:56:08.507 [Notice] Opening Control listener on /var/run/tor/control
Jan 20 20:56:08.507 [Warning] /home/ariyan/.tor is not owned by this user (root, 0) but by ariyan (1000). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Jan 20 20:56:08.508 [Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't access/create private data directory "/home/ariyan/.tor"
Jan 20 20:56:08.508 [Error] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

strange thing is running tor demon has no problem and works! but stopping it and running via Vidalia causes these problems!

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run tor as root (sudo ... ). If that does not work, file a bug report as you are using an alpha release.

Comment: I added result of running as root. strange thing is running tor demon has no problem and works! but stopping it and running via Vidalia causes these problems!

Answer (score 0):

go to Settings > Advanced > Tor Control and checked Use TCP Connection (ControlPort) with the address 127.0.0.1:9051